# Search Method for Binary Search Tree Only Returns First Match and Stops

Tags: c#, search, binary-search-tree

I am trying to search a BST for all of the nodes that contain a specific value, however when I call the search function it only returns the first match ( My test data def. has two nodes that should be returned). How do I adjust my code to get all of the values that match my criteria?

Here is my BST Search Function:

```
...
    private String search(String target, Node ptr)
    {
        ptr = root;
        if (ptr == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
    int compare = target.CompareTo(ptr.riskLevel.ToString());
        if (compare == 0)
        {
            return "Audit ID: " + ptr.auditID  + 
                "\n" + "Risk Level: " + ptr.riskLevel + 
                "\n" + "Scanner Found In: " + ptr.scanner + 
                "\n" + "Device Affected: " + ptr.boxName + 
                "\n" + "Description: " + ptr.description + "\n";
        }
        if (compare < 0)
        {
            return search(target, ptr.left);
        }
            return search(target, ptr.right);
        }
    public virtual String search(String target)
    {
        return search(target, root);
    }
```

This is my main(); where I call the search method:

```
while (true)
{
    ...
    Console.Writeline(bst.search("I"));
}
```

In other words, I'm trying to return all `Nodes` from `bst` that have a `riskLevel` of `"I"`.

Here is my output (there should be two):

[image]

My `BST` contains the following methods:

- insert()
- search()
- displayAll()
- coutnNodes()
- save()

I'm happy to post the entire `BST` class if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not traversing the tree properly.

I reused this preOrder method from a previous project and it seems to be working like I would expect.

```
public List<String> filterRiskLevel(String target, List<string> results)
{
      filterRiskLevel(target, root, results);
      return results;
}
private void search(String target, Node ptr, List<string> results)
{
     if (ptr != null)
     {
         if (ptr.riskLevel.Equals(target))
             results.Add("Audit ID: " + ptr.auditID +
                  "\n" + "Risk Level: " + ptr.riskLevel +
                  "\n" + "Scanner Found In: " + ptr.scanner +
                  "\n" + "Device Affected: " + ptr.boxName +
                  "\n" + "Description: " + ptr.description + "\n");
              filterRiskLevel(target, ptr.left, results);
              filterRiskLevel(target, ptr.right, results);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that extra results are located in the 'right' subtree of previous results.
You had some problems with your code:

1. you can only return 1 result
2. you replace the ptr node with root in the beginning?!

   ```
   private void Search(String target, Node ptr, List<string> results)
   {
       if (ptr == null)
       {
           return;
       }

       int compare = target.CompareTo(ptr.riskLevel.ToString());
       if (compare == 0)
       {
           string result = "Audit ID: " + ptr.auditID  + 
               "\n" + "Risk Level: " + ptr.riskLevel + 
               "\n" + "Scanner Found In: " + ptr.scanner + 
               "\n" + "Device Affected: " + ptr.boxName + 
               "\n" + "Description: " + ptr.description + "\n";
           results.Add(result);

           search(target, ptr.right, results);
       }
       else if (compare < 0)
       {
           search(target, ptr.left, results);
       }
       else
       {
           search(target, ptr.right, results);
       }
   }

   public virtual List<string> search(String target)
   {
       var results = new List<string>();
       search(target, root, results);
       return results;
   }
   ```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this will not return the correct results for 3 matches. Assume there will be a "root" node with the correct value (which results in the compare = 0 condition being met. Thus the right node will not be searched. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: All depends on the way the test data is structured. I should say that the left node of the second result should be empty and the third result should be in the right subtree.

Comment: This doesn't look right, your recursive calls `search(target, ptr.right)` would need to have three arguments now...

Comment: @codemonkey, what is needed in the main() to access the contents of the results? I tried `Console.Writeline(bst.search("I"));` but it does not like that...

Comment: I can image. Results is now a list of strings. You can loop over them and print them with `foreach (string r in results) Console.WriteLine(r);`

Comment: Error in the `public` method says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'`; I assume this is why I cannot access `results` in the main().

Comment: Code updated so you get the list as a result from the search method.

Comment: Made edits, it works properly now. Took your inputs and applied to them to `preOrder` answer below to get a solution. Thanks for the help @codemonkey

Comment: Unmarked this as the answer; it causes a `stackoverflowexception`